# Get top values and positions of items in list of lists

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn

I have used `sklearn` to fit and predict a model, but I want to have the top 5 predictions (in terms of probabilities) per item. 
So I used `predict_proba`, which gave me a list of lists like:

`probabilities = [[0.8,0.15,0.5,0,0],[0.4,0.6,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1]]`
What I want to do, is loop over this list of lists to give me an overview of each prediction made, along with its position in the list (which represents the classes).

When using `[i for i, j in enumerate(predicted_proba[0]) if j > 0]` it returns me `[0],[1]` , which is what I want for the complete list of lists (and if possible also with the probability next to it).

When trying to use a for-loop over the above code, it returns an `IndexError`.

Comment: can't you flatten the list and then estimate the index of possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
probabilities = [[0.8, 0.15, 0.5, 0, 0], [0.4, 0.6, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
for list in range(0,len(probabilities)):
    print("Iteration_number:", list)
    for index, prob in enumerate(probabilities[list]):
        print("index", index, "=", prob)
```

Results in:

```
Iteration_number: 0
index 0 = 0.8
index 1 = 0.15
index 2 = 0.5
index 3 = 0
index 4 = 0
Iteration_number: 1
index 0 = 0.4
index 1 = 0.6
index 2 = 0
index 3 = 0
index 4 = 0
Iteration_number: 2
index 0 = 0
index 1 = 0
index 2 = 0
index 3 = 0
index 4 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in predicted_proba:
    for index, value in enumerate(i):
        if value > 0:
            print(index)
```

Hope this helps.